# Not able to select flipkart filter in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, selenium3

I am trying to select the filter sub-section ( Left panel) in flip kart page. I am trying to expand "TYPE" section but I could not do it...

```
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=Refrigerator&otracker=start&as-show=on&as=off");
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Type']")).getText());
    Actions a = new Actions(driver);
    a.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Type']"))).click().perform();`
```

below is sample code ... Your inputs please

Comment: What us the error you are getting?

Comment: Not Getting error, It's selecting an element from Filter options ( I think first available element in filter section). I am expecting to click on the "Type" sub-section in filter which enables me to select options under it.

Answer (score 1):

Using the DevTool's Console in Chrome, I can confirm this selector works:

```
document.querySelector("#container > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(7) > section > div > div")
```

So, in Selenium code:

```
WebDriver element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#container > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div:nth-child(7) > section > div > div"));
element.click();
```

One thing I noticed is that the element is not visible in the [ViewPort](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp). So, you'll likely need to do one of the following solutions:

Scroll to the element before clicking it

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

and/or Click via JavaScript

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked for me... I would prefer to use scrollIntoView so that action will be visible.